# Failed to seek to position -1 in the stream

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I am using the SimpleHTMLDOM parser to fetch data from other sites. This is working pretty well on PHP 7.0. Since I upgraded to PHP 7.1.3, I get the following error code from file_get_contents:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): stream does not support seeking in
>   /..../test/scripts/simple_html_dom.php on line
>   75 Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to seek to position -1 in the
>   stream in
>   /..../test/scripts/simple_html_dom.php on line
>   75

**What I did**

I downgraded to PHP 7 and it works like before without any problems. Next, I looked at the code of the parser. But I didn't find anything unusual:

```
function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
{
    // We DO force the tags to be terminated.
    $dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, $target_charset, $stripRN, $defaultBRText, $defaultSpanText);
    // For sourceforge users: uncomment the next line and comment the retreive_url_contents line 2 lines down if it is not already done.
    $contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
    // Paperg - use our own mechanism for getting the contents as we want to control the timeout.
    //$contents = retrieve_url_contents($url);
    if (empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // The second parameter can force the selectors to all be lowercase.
    $dom->load($contents, $lowercase, $stripRN);
    return $dom;
}
```

The parser which I use you can find here: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The PHP function 'file_get_contents' changed in PHP 7.1 (support for negative offsets has been added), so the '-1' value of $offset used by default in Simple HTML5 Dom Parser is invalid for PHP>=7.1. You would have to put it to zero.

**I noticed that the bug has been corrected a few days ago, so this problem should not appear in the latest versions (https://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/repository/ci/3ab5ee865e460c56859f5a80d74727335f4516de/)**